# Conflicting trait implementations even though associated types differ

Tags: generics, struct, types, rust

I'm trying to an create a generic struct which wraps an `isize` or an `AtomicIsize`, but I am running into an error when I try to implement a trait for both possible implementations of the struct. I created a minimal example which demonstrates my issue below.

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicIsize, Ordering};
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Counted {
    fn inc(&self, value: isize);
}

pub type PlainCounter = isize;
pub type AtomicCounter = AtomicIsize;


pub struct Counter<'a, T: 'a> {
    counter: T,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Counter<'a, T>
    where T: Deref<Target = PlainCounter>
{
    pub fn new(counter: T) -> Self {
        Counter {
            counter: counter,
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Counted for Counter<'a, T>
    where T: Deref<Target = PlainCounter>
{
    fn inc(&self, value: isize) {
        self.counter += 1;
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Counter<'a, T>
    where T: Deref<Target = AtomicCounter>
{
    pub fn new(counter: T) -> Self {
        Counter {
            counter: counter,
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Counted for Counter<'a, T>
    where T: Deref<Target = AtomicCounter>
{
    fn inc(&self, value: isize) {
        self.counter.fetch_add(value, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac19a5a16a0a7031fa27f15894d02733&version=stable&backtrace=0))

The error I get is that the compiler found `` conflicting implementations of trait `Counted` for type `Counter<'_, _>` ``. It seems that the compiler cannot determine that the implementations are for two different types `T`, namely `T: Deref<Target = PlainCounter>` and `T: Deref<Target = AtomicCounter>`. Is there perhaps a way to provide additional information to the compiler so it can distinguish between the two cases, or am I on the wrong path entirely?

Comment: [Smaller example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=00e9ae6747f1dbb01df4070e34591732&version=stable).

Comment: I think that you are going to run into issues because you have two `impl`s that look like they can overlap, even though the associated types prevent it from actually happening. I'd probably try implementing {a, the} trait for your two concrete types and then implement it for `Counter<T> where T: Counted` and delegate.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I think that's an answer?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing an example of what you mean @Shepmaster - I think I understood what you meant but an example would be great.

Comment: @Shepmaster I took your recommendation and implemented `Counted` for both `PlainCounter` and `AtomicCounter` and then implemented `Counter<T> where T: Counted` where the calls on `Counter` just delegate to its `counter` field and everything worked out fine. I did some minor tweaking to the example to get it more in line with this new approach, example is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e091e5ceb783c67a1d36bb89c2679b54&version=stable&backtrace=0) if ypu're interested.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can accomplish this pattern by defining a second trait that does the actual work, and is implemented for `(Counter<'a, T>, <T as Deref>::Target)`, and have the `Counter` trait call out to that implementation.

I don't think that was very clear, but I think an example can illustrate well. Using Shepmaster's shorter example for clarity, we would go from this:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

trait Foo {}

impl<T> Foo for T
    where T: Deref<Target = u8>
{}

impl<T> Foo for T
    where T: Deref<Target = bool>
{}

fn main() {}
```

to this:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

trait Foo {}
trait InnerFoo {}

impl<T> Foo for T
    where T: Deref,
          (T, <T as Deref>::Target): InnerFoo
{}

impl<T> InnerFoo for (T, u8)
{}

impl<T> InnerFoo for (T, bool)
{}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: I'm finding it a little unclear — how do we actually implement functions in the inner trait which refer to `self`? It'd appear `self` would be e.g. `(T, u8)`, but presumably since we're implementing `Deref<Target=u8>` we don't actually have a concrete `u8`.

Comment: Figured it out: give `InnerFoo` a type variable `<T>`, then the trait functions' first parameter can be `t: T`. Add `<T>` to the `(T, …) : InnerFoo` constraint on Foo. Then call `<(T, <T as Deref>::Target) as InnerFoo<T>>::my_fn(self, …)`. Finally, impls of InnerFoo need the additional constraint `where T : Deref<Target=…>`. Then you can call `t.deref()` in that impl.

Comment: You can also drop the first `T` in the tuple types this way.

Comment: How this would look like for a trait like `AsRef`?

Comment: `AsRef` doesn't have an associated type, so this pattern doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is not implemented in the language yet.

There's this tracking issue: [rust-lang/rust#20400](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400).

An RFC [rust-lang/rfcs#1672](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1672#issuecomment-262152934) was also proposed to solve this problem but was then postponed waiting for [Chalk integration](https://github.com/rust-lang/chalk) which will make it easier to implement.

In the meantime, you'll have to use the workaround proposed [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408431/3799609).